# Finding the n-th prime number

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

We want to uniquely map hash values to prime numbers. One way to achieve this is storing the first $l$ prime numbers into an ordered list $L$ with size $|L| =l$. When the hash value $h$ calculated, return $L(h)$. However, when the required list size  $|L|  \approx 2^{512}$ storing the prime numbers in the list $L$ will be impractical.

Another way is; instead of storing the prime numbers, find them when the hash value occurs. So, the first question is given  $n$ find the $n$-th prime.

$$\text{find the } n\text{-th prime}, 1 \leq  n \leq |L|$$

If the finding the $n$-th prime is not (possible | practical) then we can relax the condition into finding a unique prime for each index $n, 1 \leq n \leq |L|$ so that we can map hash values uniquely into a prime number.

Comment: This is too vague.  If you have primes $p_1,\cdots, p_{n-1}$ let $p_n$ be the least prime factor of $1+\prod_{1}^{n-1} p_i$.  Of course, factoring that is very, very hard.

Comment: I agree with @lulu with respect to vagueness. Which is your criterion of impracticality? I agree with factoring being hard, but not with it being 'very very hard' (it has not been proved to be in NP-complete, it is in co-NP, and can be solved efficiently with quantum computing)

Comment: Your text is contradictory. "We can store" but "will be impractical" ???

Comment: Are you asking just to find $n$ distinct primes ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust if finding the n-th prime is not practical, giving distinct prime for each element will be enough.

Comment: @kelalaka: what ?

Comment: updated the question with your valuable comments.

Comment: You should reference https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63013/hash-to-prime-numbers which seems to give much needed context to what you're talking about.

Comment: @DanaJ I did not want to cross-question. The link you posted on crypto seems enough for me. I don't' kow how I missed that. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mathematica* uses a number of sophisticated algorithms to find the $n$th prime extremely quickly, through `Prime[n]`.  For instance, it can find the $10^{10}$th prime ($252097800623$) in $0.55$ seconds.  It also has `NextPrime[k]` which very rapidly finds the least prime above $k$.  For instance

```
NextPrime[9384759348709309384503948548553948753]
```

found the result ($9384759348709309384503948548553948859$) in less than $0.001$ second on a Mac laptop.

You mentioned specifically the "difficulties" above $2^{512}$.  *Mathematica* finds the next prime above that number ($1340780792994259709957402499820584612747936582059239337772356144372176\
4030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946\
433649006084171$) in $0.002699$ seconds.

Incidentally, this number is $2^{512} + 75$.

Comment: is there a good theory behind this?

Comment: I think much bigger than your number. [see wolframalpha 2^{512}](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Prime%5B2%5E512%5D) But. I cannot copy it.

Comment: @kelalaka Huh?  What is "much longer than [my] number"?  It is just $75$ greater than $2^{512}$.

Comment: I cannot compare directly but the number in WolframAlpha seems to have much more digits. If you have a chance can you run the same code in the WolframAlpha,too.

Comment: Indeed, nice incident.

Comment: Mathematica is not state of the art here.  Both Perl/ntheory and Walisch's primecount are *much* faster.  However finding the exact nth prime is still impractical somewhere around $10^{22}$.  Finding nextprime(n) is a completely different problem that is far easier.

Comment: @DanaJ:  "However finding the exact nth prime is still impractical somewhere around $10^{22}$."  I don't understand.  Even my randomly chosen example is $10^{37}$ and is extremely fast (less than $0.001$ second).

Comment: Your example for the nth prime was only 10 digits.  nextprime(n) is a completely different function.  The original poster wants to find the exact nth prime for arbitrary 512-bit inputs.

Comment: Oh... OK.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Out of curiosity, how long does Mathematica take for find NextPrime[10^2000] and NextPrime[10^4000]?  On my Macbook, this is 46s and 879s with Pari/GP; 13s and 216s with Perl/ntheory, with results +4561 and +16483.  All three should be using some variant of BPSW for the candidate testing.  Both non-Mathematica libraries are single threaded for this task.

Comment: @DanaJ:  *Mathematica* is faster than Pari/GP but slower than Perl/ntheory:  `NextPrime[10^(2000)]` took $25.8$ seconds and `NextPrime[10^(4000)]` took $532.2$ seconds on a Mac laptop.  (Indeed:  $+4561$ and $+16483$.)  As you said:  single-threaded.